# В visual studio текст сразу автозаменяется как убрать?

Tags: текст

Хочу вклинить допустим в текст букву, а у меня начинается замена всех букв и вообще любого текста, а хочется просто добавить чтото посередине строки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно твои шальные пальци задели кнопку Insert. Подозреваю что надо её нажать ещё раз и станет всё ванлав.

Comment: Спасибо тебе огроменное!))
как это называется на будущее?)

Comment: Называется основа из основ поведения ОС. Это будет так себя вести не только в визуал код, а во всей системе.

Comment: @КирпиковАлексей **insert** переключает режим вставки/режим замены